# Active Record: Elegant way to copy a field before update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a table with a bunch of rows that i need to update (sometimes a single row, sometimes many at once). However, before updating, I would like to copy values from 2 columns to other two.

```
id, current_tag, current_serial, previous_tag, previous_serial
```

I need to copy `current_tag -> previous_tag` and `current_serial -> previous_serial`
and then update `current_tag` and `current_serial`.

Is there an elegant/fast approach for doing that?

I am also not married to the idea of having `previous_tag` and `previous_serial` columns, but I do need a way to preserve previous values in case user needs to do a roll back?

Comment: Have you had a look at the paper_trail gem?  that would provide the kind of functionality you are looking for in a well tested manner.

Comment: @muttonlamb: whoa. this is waaaay more than i needed, but opens a way for some really cool functionality in my app! Please submit this as an answer, so I can mark it as solved! Oh, and thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider this to be a solved problem by using something like the paper_trail gem.  It would provide all of the functionality you require with very elegant rollback functionality (even beyond simply the last change made, you can have a complete history).

I've found it very easy to integrate with existing apps.

It's available here https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail

I note that this isn't the only solution, there are many others here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Versioning